# Change IE COM object UserAgent

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-11

Regarding this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638744/change-ie-user-agent), 
I need to change the UserAgent programatically (from a C# code) of a IE11 instance. I use automation (COM Internet Explorer Object):

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer()
```

As IE instances do not run in-process, using urlmon´s "UrlMkSetSessionOption" does not change UA used by iexplore.exe On the other side, add-on of EricLawrence does not allow to set programatically the new UA.

Any solution?

Comment: Please clarify: Are you saying that the browser addon DOES NOT work?

Comment: I need to change the UserAgent from a c# code.
How may I use this add-on from a c# code?
Does your addon allow to change the useragent programatically (for instance, setting a registry value) in order that i may use It from a c# Code or does It only allow to do It manually through the UI of addon?

Answer (score 0):

Eric has been very polite and he has showed me that add-on uses a registry value called "OverrideUA" in order to have a persistent configuration- That allows a programatic setting from an external code. Thead may be closed